# How to add index.php in base_url() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

In general when we use site_url() in anchor tag in php code it auto insert "index.php" before the controller like

```
/index.php/controllerName/methodName
```

But in base_url it doesn't insert "index.php". 
I want to add auto index.php before the controller how site_url() works.

Already I searched and understood that the change will be in config file.
But want to know the specific answer what I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base URL should be absolute, including the protocol:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/";
```

If using the URL helper, then base_url() will output the above string.

Passing arguments to base_url() or site_url() will result in the following

`$config['index_page'] = "index.php";:`

```
echo base_url('assets/stylesheet.css'); // http://somesite.com/somedir/assets/stylesheet.css
echo site_url('mycontroller/mymethod'); // http://somesite.com/somedir/index.php/mycontroller/mymethod
```

Comment: is it possible ?

echo base_url('assets/stylesheet.css'); // http://somesite.com/somedir/index.php/assets/stylesheet.css
echo site_url('mycontroller/mymethod'); // http://somesite.com/somedir/index.php/mycontroller/mymethod

Comment: try in your way and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: When I set $config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/index.php" then it reply double time index.php 

Like 

echo base_url('assets/stylesheet.css'); // http://somesite.com/somedir/index.php/index.php/assets/stylesheet.css

Comment: then remove 'index.php' from $config['index_page'] = "index.php"; So. your new config variable will be $config['index_page'] = "";

Comment: First of all sorry for the late reply Harsh. Ya it works !!!
Thanks a lot. But css and js file is not working now... :(...
need to change the path ...
Thanks again

Comment: no error !! I use base_url() for linking up the external CSS and JS files. but for including "index.php" in base_url() of config file,may be the path is not working.

Comment: opss...How is that ?

Comment: Have you tried like this? <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>